# UNetBootin without admin rights?

Tags: administrator, liveusb, unetbootin

Is it possible to run UNetBootin without admin privileges? I downloaded it then did `chmod +x` and then tried to run it with `./` but then a window popped up prompting for admin password. Is it not even possible to run this to create a liveUSB from an ISO, without admin rights? (where the system is not being modified).

Are there any other ways to create a live USB without admin rights if not?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to write raw data to a disk device then you need to have permission on that device. Either by being root, or by having the appropriate rights.

E.g. if I check who can write to a floppy drive I get this:

> beetle:/dev>ls -l /dev/fd0u1440
>   brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 2, 28 2012-06-06 09:42 /dev/fd0u1440

I can write to it if I am the owner (in this case root), or in the group floppy, or if I have uid 0.

The same will be true for hard drives and USB drives.
Check to which group they belong and give yourself appropriate rights.

(and remember that adding yourself to a group will be active from the next log-in.)

Comment: I have permissions on the usb and can copy files no problem, what I was referring to was writing an ISO image to create a liveUSB with a program like UNetBootin or Lili.